# Android Wear Geofence calling addGeofences-method returns Exception: 1000

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, wear-os

I am playing around with **Wear OS** on a **Fossil Falster 3** (it is running **API 28**). Also please know that I am just starting with `Kotlin`, so the code below is not good to say the least.

I want to create a Geofence using broadcast receiver.

In my `MainActivity.kt` I have the following:

```
 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    requestForegroundAndBackgroundLocationPermissions()

    val locations = arrayOf(Location("tgh", 58.798233, 11.123959))
    val geofences = locations.map {
        Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(it.name)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setCircularRegion(it.latitude, it.longitude, 100F)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
            .setLoiteringDelay(10)
            .build()
    }
    val geofencingRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        addGeofences(geofences)
    }.build()
    val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }

    val geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)
    geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, geofencePendingIntent).run {
        addOnFailureListener {
            // display error
                exception -> Log.d(TAG, "addOnFailureListener Exception: $exception")
        }
        addOnSuccessListener {
            // move on
            Log.d(TAG, "addOnSuccessListener, move on")
        }
    }
}
```

The `GeofenceReceiver` is in the same file:

```
class GeofenceReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "geofencingEvent.hasError()")
        } else {
            geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences.forEach {
                val geofence = it.requestId
                Log.d(TAG, "location at: " + geofence)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `manifest` has the following snippet:

```
<receiver android:name=".GeofenceReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

That is pretty much it. When I run the code, `addOnFailureListener` is triggered and the error message is printed and it is resulting in a  1000 exception.
[Exception 1000 according to google documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-geofence_not_available) means `GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE`. I have enabled location on both the watch and the phone to its highest level on phone (`Improve Location Accuracy is ON`). On the watch I have set to use location from both watch and phone (highest level). Still I keep getting the 1000 error code.

Comment: I am also facing same issue on wear OS 3 (Galaxy watch 4). Do you have any update regarding this?

Comment: @Nishant, No, I finally gave that up. if you find a solution you are welcome to add it.